# BeautifulSoup Grabbing a certain href link and storing it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Well this is the HTML for which I'm working with, commented is the one I wish to store.

```html
<dd>
   Wed Sep 17, 2014 1:11 am
</dd>
<dd>
</dd>
<dd>
   Forum:
   <a href="./viewforum.php?f=12">
      Minewind Chat
   </a>
</dd>
<dd>
   Thread:
   # I wish to grab this href link extension:
   <a href="./viewtopic.php?f=12&amp;t=201&amp;hilit=yeah"> 
      1.8
   </a>
</dd>
<dd>
   Replies:
   <strong>
      3
   </strong>
</dd>
<dd>
   Views:
   <strong>
      108
   </strong>
</dd>
```

I can get it to where I print both the href links with (don't know how efficient I did this):

```
cleanup = BeautifulSoup(s2.content)

for links in cleanup.find_all("dd"):
    if links.find("a") != None:
        print (links.a['href'])
```

Output:

```
./viewforum.php?f=12
./viewtopic.php?f=12&t=201&hilit=yeah
```

But how do I store the second line? Any tips please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the topic links *with one [CSS selection query](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)*:

```
topic_links = soup.select('dd a[href*=viewtopic.php]')
```

This matches links that are:

- inside `dd` tags
- contain `viewtopic.php` in the `href` attribute

The result is a list with just the matched `<a>` elements:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <dd>
...    Wed Sep 17, 2014 1:11 am
... </dd>
... <dd>
... </dd>
... <dd>
...    Forum:
...    <a href="./viewforum.php?f=12">
...       Minewind Chat
...    </a>
... </dd>
... <dd>
...    Thread:
...    # I wish to grab this href link extension:
...    <a href="./viewtopic.php?f=12&amp;t=201&amp;hilit=yeah"> 
...       1.8
...    </a>
... </dd>
... <dd>
...    Replies:
...    <strong>
...       3
...    </strong>
... </dd>
... <dd>
...    Views:
...    <strong>
...       108
...    </strong>
... </dd>
... ''')
>>> topic_links = soup.select('dd a[href*=viewtopic.php]')
>>> for link in topic_links:
...     print link['href']
... 
./viewtopic.php?f=12&t=201&hilit=yeah
```

Comment: What exactly is `'dd a[href*=viewtopic.php]'` doing? I get that it's selecting the href within dd, but what's the [] and * doing?

Comment: @Anthony: `dd a` selects `a` tags beneath `dd` tags. The `[]` part then focuses on an attribute, here `href`. The `*=` expression asks for `href` attributes that contain a given text. So any `a` element that has an `href` attribute that contains the text `viewtopic.php` qualifies.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm a little new to python, so *= is a little confusing I thought that was a multiply and assign operator.

Answer (score 0):

if you know its content you could match against the href, for example

```
if 'viewtopic' in links.a['href']:
    results.append(links.a)
```